# How to automatically click javascript link when landed to an html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a Tax Calendar link to my webpage.
This is the link:
https://www.tax.gov/calendar/

But IRS is asking visitors to click another link to show the calendar. And it looks like a deadend page.

So I want to make a link that automatically choose Grid setting
**1. Continue with calendar-month grid enabled**. which is:
javascript:continueWith('grid')

Is it possible to make a simple html link that will click this choice?

Thanks!

```
 <a href="http://www.tax.gov/calendar/" onclick="document.getElementById('grid').click() "
             target="_blank" >Tax Calendar</a>
```

and I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> document.querySelector('a[href="javascript:continueWith('grid')"]').click();</script>
          <a href="http://www.tax.gov/calendar/" 
             target="_blank" >Tax Calendar</a>
```

Comment: Your onclick function is not triggered ?

Comment: You can't control behavior on 3rd party web pages. This would be considered cross-site scripting (XSS). When I click the link my browser first redirects to a different URL before redirecting me back to the calendar page. This presumably updates some metadata in my browser localstorage. You can try sending users directly to the redirect page. https://www.tax.gov/calendar/Settings/Save?a=1&v=1&t=6

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! I really appreciate it! The redirect link tax.gov/calendar/Settings/Save?a=1&v=1&t=6 is not working or break the webpage, I get 404 server error.

Comment: And yeah, onclick function doesn't work.